# Авторизация пользователя в консольном Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

В общем ситуация такая: переводим приложение на Веб Сокеты, приложение написано на Yii2. Написал консольную команду для Yii2, которая запускает сервер сокетов и начинает слушать порт. На стороне клиента приложение соединяется с сервером сокетов, при соединении я получаю строку с куками, где есть `PHPSESSID`, `_csrf`, `_identity`. Но сессия автоматически не подхватывается (что конечно не удивительно). Как мне авторизовать пользователя в консольном Yii имея эти переменные? Или может есть какое-то другое решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал так. Беру `PHPSESSID` ищу по нему файл сессии в заданной директории, читаю его и получаю все переменные из сессии, в том числе и ID залогиненого пользователя. Добавляю в ассоциативный массив где ID => "Ресурс соединения". Вот так и работаю дальше при дальнейшем общении по сокетам, по ресурсу соединения получаю ID. Может кто-то иначе реализовал?